# Ubuntu 16.04 OpenFOAM-7 ParaView Installation Error

Tags: compiling

I'm following the [build guide provided by OpenFOAM](https://openfoam.org/download/source/software-for-compilation/), but I am having issues with an error that occurs when I try to compile ParaView with the following commands

The installation fails with the following message

```
./makeParaView


CMake Error at VTK/CMake/vtkQt.cmake:6 (message):
  Expected value for VTK_QT_VERSION is '5'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  VTK/GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tyro/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-7/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tyro/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-7/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: check this out. It worked for me. https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/219297-qt5-openfoam-7-v1906-ubuntu-18-04-a.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `qt5-devel` and use

```
./makeParaView -qmake $(which qmake-qt5)
```